# Convert Java CompletableFuture to TwitterFuture (without any intermediate Future)

Tags: java, scala

I am working with a java library in my scala code which returns a CompletableFuture.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

I have to convert this to a TwitterFuture

https://twitter.github.io/util/guide/util-cookbook/futures.html

Of course, I can convert the CompletableFuture to ScalaFuture and then ScalaFuture to TwitterFuture. but then its a waste.

Can I convert the CompletableFuture directly to TwitterFuture.

Comment: If you already know how to convert it to a scala `Future`, you can use the same approach to convert to twitter `Future` directly. There isn't any functional difference between the two, just some methods have different names, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what exactly you are asking for. Some standard method in some library? [Twitter Bijection](https://github.com/twitter/bijection) is the obvious place to look for it and there seems to be no reference of `CompletionStage` or `CompletableFuture`

If you want the code, then @Dima is right - it is not hard to write it yourself such as

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage
import java.util.function.BiConsumer
import com.twitter.util.{Future => TwitterFuture, Promise => TwitterPromise}

implicit class JavaCompletionStageTwitterOps[A](val jcs: CompletionStage[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def asTwitter(implicit e: ExecutionContext): TwitterFuture[A] = {
    val promise = new TwitterPromise[A] with BiConsumer[A, Throwable] {
      override def accept(value: A, ex: Throwable): Unit = {
        if (ex == null) this.setValue(value)
        else this.setException(ex)
      }
    }
    jcs.whenComplete(promise)
    promise
  }
}
```